# Reduce boilerplate in Play 2 controller methods

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have a Play Controller that has a couple of methods that are very similar. I wondered how I can reduce boilerplate:

```
public static Result foo() {
  // boilerplate
  if (!PREVIEW) {
    return redirect(routes.Application.login());
  }
  // other code
  ...
  return ok("...");
}

public static Result bar() {
  // boilerplate
  if (!PREVIEW) {
    return redirect(routes.Application.login());
  }
  // other code
  ...
  return ok("...");
}
```

`PREVIEW` is shorthand for a configuration setting.

Comment: I don't know Play but maybe you can add an interceptor that does the `if` check (that's how I would do it with Spring)?

Comment: @Tunaki That sounds good. How do I use an interceptor for only one controller in the Play2 framework?

Comment: I've never used Play so I can only point you to [the](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaInterceptors) [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaActionsComposition)

Comment: @Tunaki Very cool, I think I'll use that.

Comment: Yes Actions are a solution, anyway put your sample as an answer please, some other guys can upvote and use it :)

Comment: @biesior Will do. It takes two days before SO allows me to answer my own question.

Comment: @biesior Done. Apparently the 2 day limit is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I created an Action like this:

```
public class PreviewAction extends Action.Simple {
    public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        if (!PREVIEW) {
            return F.Promise.pure(redirect(routes.Application.login()));
        }
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

Now I can use an annotation on my other actions and it works like it did before:

```
@With(PreviewAction.class)
public static Result foo() {
  ...
}
```

More information: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaAsync

Thanks to Tunaki for pointing me in the right direction.